# trouble creating and saving augmented images using imgaug

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-augmentation

Using python v `3.7.3`, pytorch v `0.4.1`, imgaug `0.3.0`, windows `10`, Jupyter Notebook

I am trying to iterate through several folders containing images, augment each image 6 times, then save a hard copy of each augmented image inside that folder.  I am using the `imgaug` library to augment the images.

I am able to iterate through the folders, and augment and display the images inside the folders with this code:

```
for folder in os.listdir(path):
    for i in os.listdir(path + '\\' + folder):
        img = imageio.imread(path + '\\' + folder + '\\' + i)
        print('Original:')
        ia.imshow(img)
        img_aug = seq.augment_image(img)
        print('Augmented:')
        ia.imshow(img_aug)
```

But, I would like to ultimately augment each image 6 times and create 6 new hard files per image. I am trying to use [this tutorial](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug/issues/159) to make these changes.
Right now, I am just trying the step to save a hard copy of the augmented images.  Using this code:

```
for folder in os.listdir(path):
    for i in os.listdir(path + '\\' + folder):
        img = imageio.imread(path + '\\' + folder + '\\' + i)
        print('Original:')
        ia.imshow(img)
        img_aug = seq.augment_image(img)
        print('Augmented:')
        ia.imshow(img_aug)
for im, im_aug in enumerate(img_aug):
    imageio.imwrite(os.path.join(path, path + '\\' + folder + '\\' + folder + "%06d.png" % (im)), im_aug)
```

While the augmented images show up normally when I print them in Jupyter labs, they are being saved as a hard copy as completely flat.  It's also saving hundreds of these images:

[image]

Why would my image show up correctly augmented in Jupyter Labs, but be saved in that format when I try to save a hard copy?

Answer (score 0):

[Answered here](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug/issues/258#issuecomment-573239468), needed to be incremented:

```
for folder in os.listdir(path):
    i = 0
    for fname in os.listdir(path + '\\' + folder):
        img = imageio.imread(path + '\\' + folder + '\\' + fname)
        print('Original:')
        ia.imshow(img)
        img_aug = seq.augment_image(img)
        print('Augmented:')
        ia.imshow(img_aug)

        imageio.imwrite(os.path.join(path, path + '\\' + folder + '\\' + folder + "%06d.png" % (i,)), img_aug)
        i += 1
```